# Trouble starting a JSFL script from C#

Tags: c#, flash-cs6, jsfl, xfl

I have the following code for running a JSFL script from my ASP.Net web app:

```
Process.Start("c:\publish\build.jsfl").WaitForExit();
```

This code works fine locally on my Win 7 machine; Flash starts up, publishes the SWF, and closes. However, when I deploy it to my Windows 2008 webserver (with Flash CS6 installed), it doesn't seem to work. More specifically, when I run the code above; Flash opens up for a couple of seconds, then quits without publishing the SWF or showing/logging any error. However, if I remote into the server and simply double click that exact same script; Flash opens, the script runs, and the SWF is published. It also works if I open up the JSFL script with Flash from the command prompt on the server.

I suspect Process.Start is aborting Flash early; but I can't figure out why. As you can see, I have called WaitForExit so it blocks until the publish is finished; but it seems to quit after only a second.

Any ideas?

UPDATE

Checked the Windows System logs and found that this error was showing up every time our app attempted to launch Flash via the code above:

FlashPro Fatal Exception : FlashPro encountered a fatal exception.  FlashPro will now terminate.

Looks like it may be an issue with Flash CS6.

Comment: This is probably a problem with access rights.
Could you check whether the IIS user has the correct permissions?

Comment: IUSR permissions grant full control over the /publish/ directory as well as the JSFL build script. All build assets are located in subdirectories in the /publish/ directory with IUSR granted full control over them as well. IUSR also has read and execute permissions on Flash.exe.

Comment: Are you sure IUSR is in fact the user with which this executing?